# How to make a project internationalized in Struts 2?

Tags: java, user-interface, localization, struts2, internationalization

I want to make my project internationalized. I am giving support for the Spanish and Italian languages, but some of the characters from both of the languages (acute accent and grave accent characters) are not appearing properly on the UI.

Does anybody have the solution for this problem?

Comment: you marked this as struts2 related but didn't post the code which is yielding encoding errors. There's a million ways an encoding error could come out without being more specific!

Comment: it's not possible to copy paste the code here. I've told you the scenario and i guess that's enough for understanding like other persons have understood.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You have an encoding problem. Your server gives the pages in a different encoding, as your browser thinks, and this is because international characters appear faulty.

You need to fix the settings of your webapp and your appserver, to use the better encoding (preferable utf-8).

Comment: If there is a database connection behind your site, too, then there can exist an encoding differente between your webapp and your database. If there is no encoding deviation left, should your international characters work.

Comment: The data is not coming form the database. I've changed the hard coded lables only. In case of french it is working fine. So i guess i may have some encoding issues which i couldn't be able to locate

Comment: I you really changed everything, you didn't get this error now.

Comment: This seems like an encoding problem, not an "internationalization" one, so he should fix the title and be more specific on his problem.

Answer (score 0):

> The framework is internationalized.

You need to add the corresponding to each locale resource bundles for the localized messages that you display via the struts tags. Use `text` tag or `getText()` to retrieve a message in the UI.

The browser language is passed with the HTTP request and framework create a locale corresponding to the browser settings. Switching locale performed via passing a special parameter `request_locale` to `i18n` interceptor that should be on your stack.

You can also configure this interceptor to accept user-defined parameters.

Normally switching to a locale persist for the session of the user. So, you don't have to pass a parameter each time on every request, but this case is also supported if needed. See how could you achieve all of the above using [localization](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/localization.html).