# How to translate a DTO in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, internationalization, dto

We are working for internationalizing an old application with some dirty code. For example, we have an object DTO `InstrumentDto`:

```
private String label;
private Quotation quotation;
private ExprQuote quoteExp;

public String getTypeCouponCouru() {
    if (this.quoteExp.getCode().equals(Constants.INS_QUOTE_EXPR_PCT_NOMINAL_CPN_INCLUS)
     || this.quoteExp.getCode().equals(Constants.INS_QUOTE_EXPR_PCT_NOMINAL_INTERET)) {
        return "Coupon attaché";
    } else if(this.quoteExp.getCode().equals(Constants.INS_QUOTE_EXPR_PCT_NOMINAL_PIED_CPN)){
        return "Coupon détaché";
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}       

public String getFormattedLabel() {
    StringBuilder formattedLabel = new StringBuilder(this.label);

    Quotation quote = this.quotation;
    if (this.quotation != null) {
        formattedLabel.append(" ");
        formattedLabel.append(FormatUtil.formatDecimal(this.quotation.getCryQuote());

        if (this.quoteExp.getType().equals("PERCENT")) {
            formattedLabel.append(" %");
        } else {
            formattedLabel.append(" ");
            formattedLabel.append(this.quotation.getCurrency().getCode());
        }
        formattedLabel.append(" le ");
        formattedLabel.append(DateUtil.formatDate(this.quotation.getValoDate()));
    }
    return formattedLabel.toString();
}
```

Then, those methods are used on JSPs. For example for `getFormattedLabel()`, we have :

```xml
<s:select name = "orderUnitaryForm.fieldInstrument" 
            id = "fieldInstrument"
          list = "orderUnitaryForm.instrumentList" 
       listKey = "id" 
     listValue = "formattedLabel" />
```

IMO, the first method doesn't have its place on the DTO. We are expecting the view to manage the label to print. And in this view (the JSP), no problem to translate those words.
Additionally, this method is just used in 2 JSP. Not a problem to "repeat" the conditional tests.

But it's more difficult for `getFormattedLabel()` : this method is used in a lot of JSP, and the building of the formatted label is "complicated". And it's not possible having the i18n service in the DTO.

So how to do that ?

Comment: [Struts 2 internationalization](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20569037/573032).

Comment: I thing the problem is more complexe than just using `text` or `getText()` (or am I missing something ?)

Comment: No, it's not a problem at all, S2 i18n is a key feature of the framework for many, many years. But to use it is required some skills.

Answer (score 2):

Your code in `getFormattedLabel()` seems to be business logic.

A DTO is a simple object without any complex test/behavior (see [wiki definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)).

IMO, you should move this chunk of code to your Action and split your *.properties file like this:

Your *.properties:

```
message1= {0} % le {1}
message2= {0} {1} le {2}
```

Your Action:

```
public MyAction extends ActionSupport { 
    public String execute(){
        //useful code here
        InstrumentDto dto = new InstrumentDto();
        StringBuilder formattedLabel = new StringBuilder(label);

        if (this.quotation != null) {
            String cryQuote = FormatUtil.formatDecimal(this.quotation.getCryQuote());
            String date = DateUtil.formatDate(this.quotation.getValoDate());

            if (this.quoteExp.getType().equals("PERCENT")) {
                formattedLabel.append(getText("message1", new String[] { cryQuote, date }));
            } else {
                String cryCode = this.quotation.getCurrency().getCode();
                formattedLabel.append(getText("message2", new String[] { cryQuote, cryCode, date }));
            }   
        }
        dto.setFormattedLabel(formattedLabel);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help ;)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Yes, it does the job. But is it the best solution ? If I have to mutualise this logic in a Service (that not extends ActionSupport, so has no access to getText()), I'm blocked. Maybe the method in the service can return "message1" or "message2" and it's the action to translate it with the .properties : but how to inject parameters ? I've got in mind taglib to resolve this problem, but is it possible ?